# Selectively pass options to another method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a method `song_link` that calls `link_to` internally. I want the caller to be able to pass an options hash to `song_link`, which will then use the options relevant to it, and pass the rest to `link_to`. Here's my code:

```
  def song_link(song, separator = nil, options = {})
    if separator.class == Hash
      options = separator
      separator = nil # not sure about this logic either!
                      # I guess I should roll it into the options hash
    end

    primary_only = false
    if options[:primary_only]
      options.delete(:primary_only)
      primary_only = true
    end

    link_to title_with_artists(song, separator, primary_only), song_path(:song_slug => song.song_slug, :artist_slug => song.artist_slug), options
  end
```

I.e., I want to check to see whether `options[:primary_only]` exists, and if it does use it for `song_link`'s purposes without passing it along to `link_to`

Obviously this approach won't scale as I add more options that are relevant for `song_link` but not for `link_to`. How should I do this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Simplify the helper:**

```
def song_link(song, options = {})
  separator    = options.delete(:separator)
  primary_only = options.delete(:primary_only)

  name = title_with_artists(song, separator, primary_only)
  path = song_path(:song_slug => song.song_slug, :artist_slug => song.artist_slug)
  link_to name, path, options
end
```

Take advantage of the fact that `nil` is just as good as `false` and everything else is as good as `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Remove whatever options you process yourself from the hash before passing it along.

Comment: So basically do what I'm doing?

Comment: It's either that or pass two different options hashes.